# on tab switch event

Tags: events, firefox-addon

I was looking for an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events) that is able to run some code after clicking (changing) tab in browser, but I haven't found it.

Is it possible to achieve this event somehow?

I'm already listening to `DOMContentLoaded` event, I'm displaying some information about the current page on the status bar. When I changed tab, the information in the status bar is not correct (I have to reload the page).

thank you

Comment: You might want to reconsider doing this.  The user could be moving from your application to any other web page, so off the top of my head I can't think of a legitimate reason for trying to do this.  Maybe edit your question to tell us what you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: @David - This is actually a very common pattern, especially when you want to show something in the status bar based on what page is currently loaded. Or maybe you want the context menu to have different options based on the currently-loaded page. And so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this.

### Detecting location change

The [nsIWebProgressListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgressListener) interface is used to detect when the window's location has changed. Place something like this in your window's `onLoad` handler:

```
// implements nsIWebProgressListener
var listener = {
    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
        // fires on tab change; update status here;
        // get the currently selected tab
        var currDoc = gBrowser.contentDocument; 
    },
    onStateChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
    onProgressChange: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {},
    onStatusChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
    onSecurityChange: function(a, b, c) {}
}

gBrowser.addProgressListener(
    listener, 
    Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION);
```

Note that `onLocationChange` fires every time the window's location changes. This means that it fires when the browser is started, when a new URL is loaded in the current tab, when the tab changes, etc. This is probably what you want if your goal is to update the status bar based on the currenty-loaded URL.

### Detecting tab change

To detect only the case when a new tab has been selected, use the `TabSelect` event. Full example [copied from here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection)

```
function exampleTabSelected(event) {
  var browser = gBrowser.selectedBrowser;
  // browser is the XUL element of the browser that's just been selected
}

// During initialisation
var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;
container.addEventListener("TabSelect", exampleTabSelected, false);

// When no longer needed
container.removeEventListener("TabSelect", exampleTabSelected, false);
```

Comment: Note that onLocationChange fires early on when loading new pages too, so you'll still need the DOMContentLoaded event to handle those cases.